# Ror app not working on Heroku

Tags: heroku

**Configuration:** RoR app without models, data in database, just a simple app that has views and controllers and should be working locally and on Heroku.

I made some scaffolding using postgres and it was working locally. Pushing to Heroku went well, but then when I typed the URL of the Heroku app I received a message:

> We are sorry but something went wrong

Comment: Look at your app logs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Answer (score 0):

This command helped me:
    **heroku run rake db:migrate**